# One month gap calculation

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am trying to find the date from the database which should be exactly 30 days from now.

I want to retrieve the date from the database which is `DateTime` format. change this to timestamp with `strtotime()`. feed this to `date()` and retrieve the `m`and `i` and then do local calculation to find out if its less exactly thirty days.

I want to know if there is any straight forward and easy procedure to do this.

Comment: What DB is that? Mysql?

Comment: Everything in PHP is very well documented. Just take a look at the examples in the `strtotime()` documentation and you will find the answer in seconds: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-examples

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add number of days to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date)

Answer (score 0):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(' +30 day'));
```

this will also work

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(' +1 month'));
```

or use any format you need, but this method will compute the next date plus 30 days

[PHP strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

related answers:

1. [PHP: get next 13 dates from date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639036/php-get-next-13-dates-from-date)
2. [get next and previous day with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883571/get-next-and-previous-day-with-php)

Comment: @azamkhan, probably you will have to covert the date into datetime format for use in DB (it depends on your date format used in DB), this example ujses the Y-m-d format, you can chnage this or even use http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$date_formatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($val->time));
```

To retrieve the `m` or `i` or both, try this :

```
$v = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //test it with now.
$date_formatted = date('m i', strtotime($v));
```

For find date from database that exactly 30 days from now you can try this:

```
$date_formatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(' +30 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly do that in the SQL you can do that.

```
WHERE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = your_date_column_here
```

This way you can directly get only dates that are 1 month ahead with your query.

Or if you want to get a UNIX timestamp of the date that is one month in advance from today with PHP use this

```
strtotime('+ 1 month');
```

Using '+1 mohth' instead of '+30 days' will always give you one month ahead, not just 30 days ahead.