# Finding the number of days between two dates which is stored in m/d/Y format

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to calculate `expiry date` percentage.But my `starting date` and `expirydate` are in `m/d/Y` format.How I will find the number of days between `starting date` and `ending date`???This is my code...

```
 foreach ($result['query'] as $row) {
            $validitystart = $row->validitystart;
            $expirydate = $row->expirydate;
            $today = date('m/d/Y');
            $maxdiff = date_diff($expirydate, $validitystart);
            $diff = date_diff($expirydate, $today);
            $percentage = ($diff * 100) / $maxdiff;
        }
```

Comment: please provide your code for better understanding.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/29589066/3591273

Comment: If you are getting both values from database via query then you can do this with in query by using DATEDIFF function as `DATEDIFF(start_dat,exp_date) as diff`

Answer (score 3):

Among the hundreds of duplicates here on StackOverflow, you might have found something like this with a bit of searching

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date1);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date2);

$diffDays = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

Comment: please add reference if similar exists on this site (or elsewhere)

Comment: [how to calculate the difference between two dates using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php?rq=1)